# TouchableOpacity inside Animated.View catching gestures

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-animated

I'm trying to use `react-native-interactable` to create a component that can be moved around only once it has been pressed for a certain time (like android and ios springboard) I managed to find a solution, but my issue is that when the `Interactable.View` gets draggable, I have to remove my finger of the `TouchableOpacity` in order to move the Interactable.

I want it to be movable directly when `onLongPress` is fired but it looks like the `TouchableOpacity` is catching all the gestures.

I also want to reset `dragEnabled` to false when onPressOut is called but it doesn't seem possible with that behaviour.

Here's my code :

```js
<Interactable.View
    animatedNativeDriver={true}
    dragEnabled={this.state.editMode}    
>
    <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => alert('Touchable Pressed')}
        onLongPress={() => this.setState({editMode: true})}
    >
        <Text>Test Button</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</Interactable.View>
```